# How to change or reset parameters in the plot(ACF)-device within R-studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have estimated a two-intercept mixed multilevel-model using the function lme of the r-package nlme.

After that I checked for autocorrelation by visual inspection using the plot(ACF)-function.

Plotting for the first time I specified maxlag=16.

Now I have two problems: First, the maxlag parameter seems to be stuck somehow, i.e. further plots are all plotted with maxlag=16 even when maxlag is set to other values. 2. The plot is cropped at y=0.8 even if the value of lag 0 obviously is 1.

In the following I share the respective replex in hope of getting answers or inputs on how to solve these two issues.

[Link to the dataset and if prefered to copy-paste to the following code-script as well:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oLRfFVaoeDOaHMDy1UspZgvj-oAgkSGf)

```
#read.dataset:

datafclr <-read.csv("datafclr.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)

#required packages:

library("Matrix")
library("nlme")

#model-estimation:

tim2 <- lme(fixed=EERTmn ~ male + female + 
              (male:time7c)          + (female:time7c)          +                           
              (male:IERT_Cp)         + (female:IERT_Cp)         + 
              (male:IERT_Cp_Partner) + (female:IERT_Cp_Partner)-1,

            control=list(maxIter=100000), data=datafclr,                                             

            random=~male + female -1|dyade/female, correlation=corAR1(), na.action=na.omit)

summary(tim2)

#checking for autocorrelation:

plot(ACF(tim2, maxlag = 16), alpha = 0.01)
```

Results in the following plot:

[This results in thin plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR4VE.png)

When I change the maxlag:

```
plot(ACF(tim2, maxlag = 10), alpha = 0.01)
```

[It results in the same plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzfW4.png)

Many thanks in advance!

Best,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Joes Schwartz helped me solve these issues in the R-Studio community. For the case someone will have the same difficulties I had I'm sharing his answers here:

First issue: maxlag needs to be typed maxLag and the function works fine.

Second issue: detailed help under the following link:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/resetting-plotting-settings-plot-acf-data/19441